# Recognize title tags with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have this string that represents a `title` tag:

```
$fp = '<title>This is my title</title>';
```

I'm recognizing this string above as a title using the regular expression below:

```
$res = preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
```

The problem is that some titles have certain parameters like this below:

```
<title itemprop="name">This is my title</title>
```

As a consequence, the regular expression can not handle this type of title, in that case how could I update my regular expression to recognize both titles?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html, use an html parser, something like DOMDocument

Comment: http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html gives more examples of why you don't want to do this with regexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse `html`, use an `html` parser, something like `DOMDocument`, i.e.:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($fp);
$tags =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    print $tag->nodeValue;
}
```

If you just need 1 tag, you can use:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($fp);
print $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')[0]->nodeValue;
# or
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
print $xpath->query("//title")[0]->nodeValue;
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using a parser would be a better approach but you could look for a non greater than symbol in the `title` element.

```
<title[^>]*>(.*)<\/title>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BLllhw/1/

Answer (score 1):

Basically @chris85 idea from comment, but fine tuned.

```
$res = preg_match("/<title[^>]*>(.*)<\/title>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
```

Comment: What is fine tuned? Isn't this my answer/comment?

Comment: It is your answer, which we created at the same time. Fine tuned from your (now deleted) comment, by not requiring at least one of the non-`>`.Sorry, I thought you were done and moved on.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you out..

**Regex:** `<title[^>]*>\s*\K.*?(?=<\/title>)`

> **1.** `<title[^>]*>` this will match `<title` and till `>`
>
> **2.** `\s*\K.*?(?=<\/title>)*` optionally contain spaces `\s*`, `\K` will reset current match , `.*?` this will match all till and positively look ahead for `</title>)`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784824)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$fp='<title itemprop="name">This is my title</title>';
$res = preg_match("/<title[^>]*>\s*\K.*?(?=<\/title>)/", $fp, $title_matches);
print_r($title_matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is my title
)
```

Comment: @chris85 yaahh.. i think you are right... let me check..

Comment: @SahilGulati While I appreciated learning about `\K`, I still wonder why the effort. OP seems satisfied with using the capture group and I (currently, with lack of experience) perceive the resetting construct to be more effort for the same result. (By the way, I deleted other comments, you might want to do so, too, to minimise confusion for others.)

Comment: What if it's `$fp="<title>\nthis is my title\n\n</title>"`?  What if there are two `<title>` tags but the first one is commented out?